# Task failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\amir.khan\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_local_notifications-14.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications'.

> No signature of method: build_7harwrcn8ivgvwylv8lrhblgi.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7harwrcn8ivgvwylv8lrhblgi$_run_closure2) values: [build_7harwrcn8ivgvwylv8lrhblgi$_run_closure2@665af093]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 483
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_local_notifications'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,839ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

how to solve this problem? Build completed with 2 failures.

Comment: Update the pub flutter_local_notifications, this could solve your problem. If not, let me know and I'll provide more support, happy coding!

Comment: ```flutter clean``` then ```flutter pub upgrade``` and try

Comment: jdk 17 and android version 22.3 but showing error  dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath  "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
        //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // add this line
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"//->added
    } distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip